# Get element depending on value of attribute within

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a XML document laid out like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mailmanager xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <locations>
<store id="57fb3dc3-8716-4a71-ab5c-d8c76e20640b">
  <type>msg</type>
  <description>01038 - Wood Wharf - Fire</description>    <folder>SharePoint:https://site.domain.com/legal/01038/documents/Forms/CRMView.aspx</folder>
</store>
<store id="6873a00e-e49c-4602-af27-49d2900563d3">
  <type>msg</type>
  <description>01038 - Wood Wharf - Fire</description>
  <folder>\\site.domain.com\legal\01038\documents\</folder>
  <fileable>0</fileable>
</store>
<store id="d5e3af58-bc1d-4e45-a2dc-a9ceed803456">
  <type>msg</type>
  <description>05515 - IRELAND - Dart Underground   -  DART UNDERGROUND INTERCONNECTOR PROJECT</description>     <folder>SharePoint:https://site.domain.com/legal/05515/documents/Forms/CRMView.aspx</folder>
</store>
```

With thousands of `store` elements.

With PowerShell, is it possible to get an entire parent element (i.e. store with everything within) based on the `folder` value? So if `folder` value contains `site.domain.com/legal/02323` for example, I get the parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just select all stores and filter the one which folder child contain a specific value using the `Where-Object` cmdlet:

```
[xml]$content = Get-Content 'your_xml'
$content.mailmanager.locations.store | 
    Where-Object { $_.folder -eq '\\site.domain.com\legal\01038\documents\' }
```

**Output:**

```
id          : 6873a00e-e49c-4602-af27-49d2900563d3
type        : msg
description : 01038 - Wood Wharf - Fire
folder      : \\site.domain.com\legal\01038\documents\
fileable    : 0
```

Comment: Brillaint, this works! What object is returned? IE if I store the result in a variable, could I call delete on it? EDIT: Looks like xmlelement is returned, I would need to work out how best to delete the found element.

Comment: Just assign the output to lets say `$obj` and do something like this: `$obj.ParentNode.RemoveChild($obj)`

Comment: Perfect one more question, how can I get the entire body of xml to then save it to file?

Comment: You just do `$content.Save('YourFilePath')`

Comment: Perfect thanks! If I do the modification of the xml in that order like you suggest and then save, I would assume the save captures the removal of the node?

Comment: Yes, It will capture it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using an XPath expression with the [`contains()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains):

```
$Search = "site.domain.com/legal/01038"
$XmlDoc = [xml](Get-Content .\mydocument.xml)
$StoreNode = $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//store[folder[contains(.,'$search')]]")
```

You could also do the above with the [`Select-Xml` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849968.aspx):

```
$Search = "site.domain.com/legal/01038"
$StoreNode = Select-Xml -Path .\mydocument.xml -XPath "//store[folder[contains(.,'$search')]]" |Select-Object -Expand Node
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use XPath for this:

```
$document = New-Object System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument("C:\Path\To\XmlFile.xml")
$navigator = $document.CreateNavigator()
$navigator.Select("//store[folder='SharePoint:https://site.domain.com/legal/01038/documents/Forms/CRMView.aspx']")
```